Проблема с записью экрана geforce experience
Дело такое, сейчас в компьютере стоит GTX1660, до этого стояла GTX770, но проблемы в целом одни и те же! Если начинаю запись видео в играх через Geforce Experience! проблем нет, могу записывать сколько места на диске хватает, а вот если начинаю делать запись рабочего стола, браузера и т.д не в играх, а просто даже момента какой-то с ютуба, картинка может в начале, может на середине просто остановится, зависнуть, но при этом звук продолжает работать, всё нормально идёт кроме картинки! Она статично зависает в одном моменте и всё, дальше никак! От чего может быть эта проблема? Причём бывает по разному, иногда всё нормально, но если она залипнет после записи то все остальные видео будут такие-же но как я уже писал, в играх таких проблем нет. Подскажите пожалуйста что с этим можно сделать? Только что момент заснял, отправил другу (видео идёт 40сек) на 15 сек оно залипло.
